# adjacency matrix don't alloc properly

Tags: c, graph, malloc, adjacency-matrix

I have a graph structure with `v` representing number of nodes, and `**adjmatrix` which is the adjacency matrix, i have a problem to initialize all elements with 0, I get segmentation fault at `adjmatrix[0][0]=0`.

The structure looks like this:

```
struct Graph {
    int V;
    int **adjmatrix;
};
```

And this is the function to initialize the graph:

```
struct Graph *createGraph(int V) {
    struct Graph *graph = (struct Graph *)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->V = V;
    graph->adjmatrix = (int *)malloc(V * V * sizeof(int));
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < V; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < V; j++) {
            graph->adjmatrix[i][j] = 0; //here is where i get segmentation fault
        }
    }
    return graph;
}
```

Comment: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 0):

```
   graph->adjmatrix = (int **)malloc(V * sizeof(int*));
        graph->adjmatrix = (int *)malloc(V * V * sizeof(int));
```

is not correct.
What you need to do is:

```
graph->adjmatrix=malloc(V*sizeof(int *));
for (int i=0;i<V;i++){
    graph->adjmatrix[i]=malloc(V*sizeof(int));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You allocate space for a compact 2D matrix, but the type of `adjmatrix` implies an indirect 2D matrix, ie: a pointer to an array of `V` pointers to arrays of `V` integers.

You can allocate this with a loop and `calloc()` so it is already initialized to `0`:

```c
struct Graph *createGraph(int V) {
    struct Graph *graph = malloc(sizeof(*graph));
    graph->V = V;
    graph->adjmatrix = calloc(V, sizeof(*graph->adjmatrix));
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        graph->adjmatrix[i] = calloc(V, sizeof(*graph->adjmatrix[i]));
    }
    return graph;
}
```